# Change Regular Expression to NFA and then to DFA in python using Thomsons Construction and Subset Construction

Tags: python, compiler-construction

I need to convert the Regular Expression inputted having alphabets = {a,b} and the operations to be included are Concatenation, Union, Kleene Closure, somewhat of the form (a|b)*abab.

Would someone suggest how I can implement it in Python? Is there any function or so in Python for this, and if so, please tell me how to use it. If not, then please tell me how to code it from scratch. I have been trying to figure out how to write an effective code for this, but each time I have an error or I have wrong output.

Comment: When asking questions, please refrain from adding "I've been stuck for X time" and "please help me" pleading. We try to discourage chatty material. We do encourage specific and focussed questions, and furthermore I fear your question is rather too broad. "Please provide the code for me" is a request for free work, and that's a lot to ask of volunteers, especially if you have not done any prior work yourself.

Comment: Actually it's my first question, so I didn't know how to write at this. Sorry for that. Actually I had done some work but was stuck in one of the steps and I'm neither sure that I'm correct. That's why my question was so broad. Sorry for that and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks halfer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer to the above question has been put on github. The link for the same is =>
[Compilers](https://github.com/ChandanSuri/CompilerAssignment)